# How to allow only continuous data entry?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want my data entry to be continuous, I don't want any rows to get skipped(or be blank) in between.
How can I make this happen?
[image]
After the data entry on 4th row, next allowed entry should only on 5th row. Data entry on 6th row or after shouldn't be allowed itself.

**ANSWER:**

Please see the accepted answer which is by @JoeW
**Appendment:**
We can have multiple data validations for one cell with just playing around with the custom formula in Data Validation to include `=NOT(ISBLANK($A1))`.
*For Example:* I want column A to have only numbers & allow only continuous values so my formula becomes: `=IF(AND(ISNUMBER($A2),NOT(ISBLANK($A1))),TRUE)` similarly I could use `=ISDATE($A2)` for date validation.

Comment: How is the data being entered?

Comment: I edited the question, please check!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another simple way (without writing a lot of code to protect the sheet and change the protected ranges each time a row is added) would be to use Data Validation.
It's not 100% secure as people could turn off the data validation but it's the easiest way to achieve what you're looking for.
Here's an example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Obv0ZbhyHnuV7xvlG4f9QsLnrQwqo-S1j9cUI8yDLmk/edit#gid=633591940

Basically, I highlighted all the cells from A2:Z1000 (the whole sheet except the top row)
Then click Data>Data Validation
and use these options:
[image]

```
[Custom formula is]
[ =NOT(ISBLANK($A1)) ]
[x] Reject Input 
[x] Show validation help text:
[ Please use the next empty row ]
```

This will only let people edit the row if the A column of the row above has been filled in.

**UPDATE:**

Or, if you need to keep your data validation, what about just greying out all the lower cells so users will not use them?

```
Again, Highlight A2:Z1000, Select Format>Conditional Formatting, 
Apply to range [A2:Z1000]
Format rule is [Custom Formula Is]
[=ISBLANK($A1)]
Formatting Style: Gray background & Font
```

Still not flawless as users COULD still enter data into lower cells but it might help direct them. Also, if you already have some CF rules, drag this one up to the top and it will still grey out rows below the next blank row but after that, the other CF rules will still work.

If this isnt the answer you need, Could you recreate a copy of your sheet with just a couple of example rows (not real data obviously) and click [Share>Anyone with link>Editor] and post the link here, there would probably be a way of keeping all the current Data Validation rules while beig able to add another.

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for **but I cannot use this because it removes all other data validations in the whole sheet.** (It cannot be compromised because having data validations for Date columns, checkbox column many more are must!)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, I realized we can have multiple data validations for one cell with just playing around with the custom formula in Data Validation to include `=NOT(ISBLANK($A1))`.
For Example: I want column A to have only numbers & allow only continuous values so my formula becomes: `=IF(AND(ISNUMBER($A2),NOT(ISBLANK($A1))),TRUE)` similarly I could use `=ISDATE($A2)` for date validation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a way of doing this without some very complicated Apps Script code. What you could do is have a Query on another sheet pulling in just the information that you need, so say your first sheet is called `Sheet1`, make a second sheet (`Sheet2`) and put this code in the first cell:

```
=QUERY(A1:Z,"Select * Where A is not null",-1)
```

This should show only the data from the first sheet and ignore any blank rows (or any rows where no data has been entered into the first cell)

Comment: Nope, That is **not** something I want!

Comment: So you want to lock the whole document from being edited apart from the line underneath the last completed row?

Comment: THAT IS EXACLTY WHAT I WANT

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Obv0ZbhyHnuV7xvlG4f9QsLnrQwqo-S1j9cUI8yDLmk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Consider [creating a form](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6281888) instead of sharing a spreadsheet for data entry.

Form responses automatically appear in a separate tab in the spreadsheet in a row-oriented fashion without gaps and are thus easy to process with spreadsheet functions such as `query()` and `filter()`.

Comment: Thank you! but in my use case using form is not an option at all